# How to join two Datasets using only Dataset API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am struggling to flatten the dataset resulting from joining two other datasets. 
Below is my code :

```
  val family = Seq(
      Person(0, "Agata", 0),
      Person(1, "Iweta", 0),
      Person(2, "Patryk", 2),
      Person(3, "Maksym", 0)).toDS
    val cities = Seq(
      City(0, "Warsaw"),
      City(1, "Washington"),
      City(2, "Sopot")).toDS
```

then the join :

```
val joined = family.joinWith(cities, family("cityId") ===cities("id"),"crossjoin")
```

The obtained result is :

```
joined: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Person, City)]
 _1| _2|

[0,Agata,0]|[0,Warsaw]| | 
[1,Iweta,0]|[0,Warsaw]| |
[2,Patryk,2]| [2,Sopot]| |
[3,Maksym,0]|[0,Warsaw] |
```

I want to flatten this and to get the following dataset :

```
val output: Dataset= 
[0,Agata,0,Warsaw]|
[1,Iweta,0,Warsaw]|
[2,Patryk,2,Sopot]| 
[3,Maksym,0,Warsaw]
```

Any idea how to do this without using dataframe API , I want it to be totally done with Dataset API. 
Thanks a lot for your help. 
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Using join itself, You will get the same output.

```
family.join(cities, family("cityId")===cities("id")).drop("id")
```

Sample Output:

```
+--------+------+--------+
|cityName|cityId|cityName|
+--------+------+--------+
|   Agata|     0|  Warsaw|
|   Iweta|     0|  Warsaw|
|  Patryk|     2|   Sopot|
|  Maksym|     0|  Warsaw|
+--------+------+--------+
```

Comment: with this solution you are  rather using the dataframe API. My aim is to do it in datset API only

Comment: missing a column in display output, wondering why so finnicky with the DS vs DF?

Comment: @thebluephantom Which column id? I dropped the id column.

Comment: I want to join the two datasets on separate columns, so where TypeA.ColumnA == TypeB.ColumnB. Spark offers the function JoinWith on a dataset, which I think will do this properly, but the function is undocumented and marked as "experimental". NOTE EXPERIMENTAL